# Excel returning 0

Tags: php, sql-server, excel, sqlsrv

Trying to generate excel file from my sql server, but it's returning 0 in the excel file. Not sure why.

SQLSRV version which returns 0 in the excel document.

```
 $result=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . sqlsrv_error(). "<br>" . sqlsrv_errno()); 


$file_ending = "xls";
$reals=array();
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields

/*for ($i = 0; $i < sqlsrv_num_fields($result); $i++) {
    $type = sqlsrv_field_metadata($result,$i);
    echo sqlsrv_field_metadata($result,$i) . "\t";
    if ($type == "real")
    {
        $reals[] = $i;
    }
}
*/
$i=0;
foreach( sqlsrv_field_metadata( $result ) as $fieldMetadata ) {    
       echo $fieldMetadata["Name"]+"\t";
       if($fieldMetadata["Type"]=="real")//$fieldMetadata["Type"]=== SQL_REAL
       {
           $reals[] = $i;
       }
       $i++;
}


print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch($result))
{
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j<sqlsrv_num_fields($result);$j++)
    {
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != ""){
            if (in_array($j, $reals)){
                $schema_insert .= str_replace(".",",","$row[$j]").$sep;
            } else {
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            }
        }
        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";

}
```

MYSQL version, which works perfectly:

```
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";
$reals=array();
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
    $type = mysql_field_type($result,$i);
    echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
    if ($type == "real")
    {
        $reals[] = $i;
    }
}



print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
    {
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != ""){
            if (in_array($j, $reals)){
                $schema_insert .= str_replace(".",",","$row[$j]").$sep;
            } else {
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            }
        }
        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: If you want to get data from result set, you should use `sqlsrv_fectch()` or `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` functions. num_fields or num_rows returns you the number of rows or fields, not data in the row or fields.

Comment: Hello! thanks for helping, I have edited the post above. I have pasted the mysql version which works perfect, and I have tried to convert those functions to sqlsrv. Hope you can give me a hand on that. Have been trying it for over 1 week now :(

Answer (score 0):

`sqlsrv_fetch()` makes the next result set available for reading so, if you want to read data as `$row[$j]`, you should use `sqlsrv_get_field($result, $j)`:

```
while(sqlsrv_fetch($result))
{
   $schema_insert = "";
   for($j = 0; $j < sqlsrv_num_fields($result); $j++)
   {
      if (sqlsrv_get_field($result, $j) != "") {
         if (in_array($j, $reals)) {
            $schema_insert .= str_replace(".",",", sqlsrv_get_field($result, $j)) . $sep;
         } else {
            $schema_insert .= sqlsrv_get_field($result, $j) . $sep;
         }
      }
      else
         $schema_insert .= "" . $sep;
   }
   $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
   $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
   $schema_insert .= "\t";
   print(trim($schema_insert));
   print "\n";
}
```

Note that I removed `if(isset($row[$j]))` check as it is unneccessary.

One more way(and less complicated I think for your use) is to use `sqlsrv_fetch_array()`. If you won't return a field value as a specific type(e.g. string), you can use that function to return result sets as arrays:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{
   $schema_insert = "";
   for($j = 0; $j < sqlsrv_num_fields($result); $j++)
   {
      if ($row[$j] != "") {
         if (in_array($j, $reals)) {
            $schema_insert .= str_replace(".",",", $row[$j]) . $sep;
         } else {
            $schema_insert .= $row[$j] . $sep;
         }
      }
      else
         $schema_insert .= "" . $sep;
   }
   $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
   $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
   $schema_insert .= "\t";
   print(trim($schema_insert));
   print "\n";
}
```

One more thing to add, I removed also double quotes from around of `$row[$j]` however I'm not sure so you can add them again.

You should refer more to the documentation. It has very clear examples with very good explanations.

- [SQLSRV Driver API Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296152%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [SQLSRV Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sqlsrv.php)

Comment: Thanks for helping! I used the less complicated: sqlsrv_fetch_array. But it's really weird it's still returning 0 to the excel document. Do you think the sqlsrv_field_metadata correct with name and type ?

Comment: It's correct I think, however it's a bit upto you, if you think something is wrong, try echo that think or log to error with `error_log()`. I suggest logging many things like `$fieldMetadata`, `sqlsrv_num_fields($result)`, `$row`. Problem should be narrowed down to be figured out what causes to write 0 to excel.